# Podman network cannot resolve container name

Tags: podman

I follow a podman tutorial,which shows multi containers interacting in same network.

```
$ podman network create foo
/home/user/.config/cni/net.d/foo.conflist
$ podman run -d --name web --hostname web --network foo nginx:alpine
$ podman run --rm --network foo alpine wget -O - http://web.dns.podman
```

The expected result is

```
Connecting to web.dns.podman (10.88.4.6:80)
...
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
...
```

But I got

```
wget: bad address 'web.dns.podman'
```

I guess container network dns fail,But container can resolve other network domain like [www.baidu.com](http://www.baidu.com) normally,it just cannot resolve container name.I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

## PreRequirements:

First you have to install `podman-plugins & containernetworking-plugins` using this command:

```
$ sudo dnf -y install podman-plugins containernetworking-plugins
```

It's required to run this command before network creation. If you already created your network, consider creating a fresh network after installing the packages.
rt the system after installation.

## Unix Domain Sockets:

*****This is the best option I ever tried.*****

As an stable and reliable option you can use Unix Domain Sockets and share them through named volumes.

**Don't forget to use volumes with this flags to be writeable by container: "rw,z"**.

## The TCP Solution:

Then you should be able to communicate inter-container using container names.

### Same Pod

If they are in the same pod, it's enough to call the container alias, Like:

```
$ podman network create foo
$ podman pod create --name=ptestpod
$ podman run -d --name web1 --pod=testpod --network foo nginx:alpine
$ podman run -d --name web2 --pod=testpod --network foo nginx:alpine
```

In the **web1** container you can simply `ping web2` and vise versa, It's working.

### Different Pod

If they are not in the same pod but same network, the full name will work. For Example:

```
$ podman network create foo
$ podman pod create  --name=testpod1
$ podman run -d --name web1 --pod=testpod1 --network foo nginx:alpine
$ podman pod create  --name=testpod2
$ podman run -d --name web2 --pod=testpod2 --network foo nginx:alpine
```

In this case you should just use fullname. In the **web1** container you can `ping testpod2_web2_1` and it works!

### Notice:

- If you are not using pods the second case will work everywhere.
- It's not a problem for containers to register on multiple networks. But the containers must have at least one common network.
- It's important to keep just one network `DNS` enabled. If more than one network with enabled `dns` is connected to container it will fail to resolve anything.

Comment: Why add the '_1' at the end in the second case? Also it seems to work intermittently. I run the example you gave and do 100 times the command `podman exec -it web1 sh -c 'ping -c 1 web2'` and get about a 5 failures with the error: `ping: bad address 'web2'`

Comment: The ping bad address is an issue in podman default network and I'm still working to find a solution for it. But it works most of the time. _1 is the number of same container services in the pod for scalability.

Comment: If you want a stable networking in podman change network backends to cni and it works like a charm

Comment: I tried both CNI and Netvark and see the same flaky, intermittent issue.

Comment: probably your changes to CNI not applied... I tried everything and didn't find any issues with CNI. CNI is the same networking stack that is being used in K8s! :)

Comment: @Plazgoth If you didn't find a way just use **Unix Domain Sockets** and share it through 
named volumes using this flags: "rw,z"

Comment: Any link to documentation on how to do that. I confirmed CNI is indeed the backend being used, and I saw the same instability.

Comment: At the latest versions netavark is more stable, but as i said use unix domains in named volume. Simpler and more performant.

Comment: Only had to install the additional plugins to get containers talking within a network.  How odd to to include podman in RHEL8, but not the plugins for the networking...

Answer (score 1):

Did you find a solution? This problem is preventing me form using `podman-compose`.

My setting is:

- Podman v 4.3.0
- Arch Linux, kernel 6.0.7
- `slirp4netns` (v 2.5.4) installed

The communication within a pod works as expected, but across containers from different pods, the hostname do net get resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, I found out, what my problem was. I don't know, if it helps in your case.

On my machine, the package `podman-dnsname` (install it from [here](https://github.com/containers/dnsname) or from the package respository of your distro) was missing.